# How to Graph Parametric Function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would appreciate any help graphing the function given by:

[image]

Which should look somewhat like this:

[image]

I'm not sure how to create the open dots and the part of f(x) where x < 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd just draw separate plots.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,decorations.text}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle,draw,inner  sep=2pt}]
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xmin=-4.5,
    xmax=6.5,ymin=-2,
    %xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
    xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},
    minor tick num=4,
    grid=both,
    every tick label/.style={opacity=0},
]
  \addplot [cyan,smooth,{Stealth[bend]}-,domain=-4:2,
  postaction={decoration={text along path,text align={align=center},
      text={|\color{cyan}|{$y$}{${}={}$}{${x^2}$}},raise=-2.5ex,},decorate}]{x*x} 
      node[pos=1,circ,fill=white]{};
  \path (2,6) node[circ,fill=green!60]{};
  \addplot[cyan,samples=2,domain=2:6] {10-x}
  node[pos=0,circ,fill=white]{}
  node[pos=0.5,above,sloped]{$y=10-x$}
  node[pos=1,circ,fill=green!60]{};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]